# relation between fetcher.server.min.delay and fetcher.threads.fetch in nutch 1.13

Tags: nutch

i am running nutch in local mode with server configuration of 64 GB RAM and 32 processor.if i have one url in the seedlist and have below configuration in nutchsite.xml

```
fetcher.threads.fetch =16
fetcher.threads.per.queue=2
fetcher.max.crawl.delay=120
fetcher.queue.depth.multiplier=150
fetcher.queue.mode=byHost
```

how many request will be made to the url in the Fetch phase if -topN is set to 1000
will multiple map task be created for Fetcher , what i understand is single map task is created irrespective of the number of urls that need to be fetched from  fetchlist 
i tried googling the relation between fetcher.threads.fetch with fetcher.threads.per.queue but dint find anything that was clear 
also adding logs from fetcher Phase

```
FetcherThread INFO  fetcher.FetcherThread (277) - fetching 
http://investors.te.com/news-releases/press-release-details/2018/TE- 
Connectivity-announces-fourth-quarter-and-full-year-resu
lts-for-fiscal-year-2018/default.aspx (queue crawl delay=2000ms)
FetcherThread INFO  fetcher.FetcherThread (277) - fetching http://investors.te.com/shareholder-info/default.aspx (queue crawl delay=2000ms)
FetcherThread INFO  fetcher.FetcherThread (277) - fetching https://investors.te.com/news-releases/press-release-details/2019/TE-Connectivity-to-hold-annual-general-meeting-of-shareholders-on-March-13-2019/default.aspx (queue crawl delay=2000ms)
FetcherThread INFO  fetcher.FetcherThread (277) - fetching https://investors.te.com/investor-resources/request-information/default.aspx (queue crawl delay=2000ms)
FetcherThread INFO  fetcher.FetcherThread (277) - fetching https://investors.te.com/investor-resources/email-alerts/default.aspx (queue crawl delay=10000ms)
FetcherThread INFO  fetcher.FetcherThread (277) - fetching https://investors.te.com/site-map/default.aspx (queue crawl delay=10000ms)
FetcherThread INFO  fetcher.FetcherThread (277) - fetching https://investors.te.com/rss/PressRelease.aspx?LanguageId=1&CategoryWorkflowId=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000&tags= (queue crawl delay=10000ms)
FetcherThread INFO  fetcher.FetcherThread (277) - fetching https://investors.te.com/stock-information/quote-and-chart/default.aspx (queue crawl delay=10000ms)
FetcherThread INFO  fetcher.FetcherThread (277) - fetching https://investors.te.com/investor-resources/overview/default.aspx (queue crawl delay=10000ms)
FetcherThread INFO  fetcher.FetcherThread (277) - fetching https://investors.te.com/investor-resources/investor-contacts/default.aspx (queue crawl delay=10000ms)
FetcherThread INFO  fetcher.FetcherThread (277) - fetching https://investors.te.com/js/mobileRedirect.js (queue crawl delay=10000ms)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will only a single request because there is only one URL. If there are two URLs from a single host with `fetcher.threads.per.queue=2` there can be two simultaneous requests to the same host. A high number of `fetcher.threads.fetch` only makes sense if you have a large number of hosts to be crawled, or you're crawling your own local fast and responsive web server. In the latter case `fetcher.threads.per.queue` should be equal or close to `fetcher.threads.fetch`. If it's not your own server and you're not explicitly allowed you should always keep the default for `fetcher.threads.per.queue` which is a single thread (=1) with no parallel connections to the same host and a guaranteed delay between successive requests.

Comment: i have 4 instances of nutch in local mode on same server each taking 1 seedurl and crawling till the depth of 4.i want to crawl 500 urls in a day which is not in local and the url i am trying to crawl could be  fast or slow responding server, but the there is a java process which takes care of adding only one url to the seed file of each nutch instances at any point . So if i get it right as per you answer only one url will be fetched for each host(seed url) at every depth by a nutch instance provided i keep the fetcher.threads.per.queue=fetcher.threads.fetch=1. is this the best configuration?

Comment: No, the max number of URLs fetched per cycle (depth level) is defined by -topN passed to the generator. Even with a single seed URL in further cycles it's likely you get URLs from many hosts and you may want to assign more fetcher threads to parallelize and speed-up the fetching. Btw., it may be worth to use only a single Nutch instance and track/limit the depth starting from the seed URL using the plugin "scoring-depth".

Comment: I din't type  my question correctly what i wanted to know is how many outlinks will be fetched in parallel from the same host.What i understand now is with fetcher.threads.per.queue=1 will have single request to a individual host and fetcher.threads.fetch=16 will help to query multiple hosts at given point. so if my seed url has 20 different host in its outlink 16 calls will be made from nutch on 16 different host at a given point and if all the outlinks are from same host only one request will be made at a given point

Comment: with fetcher.threads.per.queue=10 and etcher.threads.fetch=16  rest of the config is same as in the question for seed url http://investors.te.com/investor-home/default.aspx i have attached the log in the question , why there are two different crawl delay time could it be because they belong to two different host

Comment: The [robots.txt can define a host-specific crawl-delay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard#Crawl-delay_directive). As soon as the robots.txt has been fetched (after the second page fetched with `fetcher.threads.per.queue=2`) the crawl-delay from the robots.txt is used:
```
User-agent: *
Crawl-delay: 10
Allow: /
```

Comment: is robots.txt called for every outlink that is fetched for a seed url?the robots.txt that i found for the url https://www.te.com/robots.txt don't have any crawl-delay attribute in it.and as per the nutch-site.xml if fetcher.threads.per.queue > 1 Crawl-Delay value from robots.txt is ignored and the value of fetcher.server.min.delay will be used

Comment: You need to look into http://investors.te.com/robots.txt and https://investors.te.com/robots.txt and this crawl-delay is logged. However, you're right with fetcher.threads.per.queue > 1 the value of fetcher.server.min.delay is used. Needless to say that you only should modify fetcher.threads.per.queue if the owners of investors.te.com allow you to crawl their site with a lower delay than specified in their robots.txt. The robots.txt is fetched once per protocol://host:port/ immediately before the first page is of this host is fetched.

Comment: http://www.files.services/open.php?id=51774&file=http://www.files.services/files/402/2019/0130/20190130224901_23177965_en.pdf (queue crawl delay=2000ms)http://www.wesolutions.com.hk/tc/about_reports.php (queue crawl delay=10000ms)  fetcher.server.min.delay =1 and fetcher.threads.per.queue > 1 the crawl delay in robots.txt for each host is 10 which will not be considered from where is the delay set then . and url from http://www.files.services is not fetched is it because of Disallow: / in robots.txt